# How to load and bind a image contained in a portable library within an UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm doing an UWP app, and I'm having an hard time to load and bind an image with an UWP app, how should it be done?

My current structure:

```
MyApp.Model:
 |
 |-Models
   |-MyModel.cs
   |-MyModelContainer.cs
 |-Resources
   |-image1.png
   |-image2.png
   |-image3.png
```

My Xaml is in another project(win 10 universal app and reference this Portable class library.)

`MyModelContainer` is only a singleton container that instantiate a `IEnumerable<MyModel>`. Here are their content:

```
public class MyModel{
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public ??????? Icon {get;set;}
}

public static class MyModelContainer{
    private static IEnumerable<MyModel> _myModelList;

    public static IEnumerable<MyModel> MyModelList{get{
        if(_myModelList==null){
            Initialize();
        }
        return _myModelList;
    }}

    private static Initialize(){
        _myModelList = new List<MyModel>() {
            new MyModel(){
                Name = "Model one"
                Icon = ???????
            }
        };
    }
}
```

At some place in my XAML I receive a list of `MyModel`, in a `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelListProperty}"  >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Button Margin="10" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="40"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" ></Image>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>^
```

My questions:

1. What is the type of property that I should use to bind an image(I tought it was `BitmapImage`?
2. How should I create this property? I tried `Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://MyApp.Model/Resources/image1.png"))` without any luck, I have no image loaded(and the ImageFailed event is triggered).
3. How should I bind this property to the `<Image/>` ?

This is for an UWP(windows 10) app, not WPF, not win8.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

Here is the folder structure

```
MyApp == AstroApp
MyApp.Model == AstroApp.Model
MyModel = AstroSign
MyModelContainer = AstroManager
```

[image]

Comment: Try this  <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" ImageFailed="BitmapImage_ImageFailed"/>
                 </Image.Source>

Comment: @LovetoCode And how is created ImageUrl? Is it a String or an URI, what is it format?

Comment: Its in string. Or just give url to Source property. BitmapImage will be created automatically.    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" ></Image>. Let Icon be "ms-appx:///MyApp.Model/Resources/image1.png"

Comment: @LovetoCode and what should be the build action of the image?

Comment: build action will be Content

Comment: @LovetoCode `Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.String' to type 'Uri';` but even after I changed the type to `Uri`, I've the `ImageFailed` event triggered

Comment: IS MyApp.Model folder name or project name?And where does you view page residing . Please show the complete structure

Comment: @LovetoCode It's the project name, and there is only the "Resources" folder in it with the PNG's inside

Comment: OK. then it must be ms-appx:///Resources/image1.png. When you used just string was it runtime exception or compile time?

Comment: If you send the screenshot of the project structure would be helpfull

Comment: @LovetoCode Well, give me 5min to take the screenshots. How would the the UWP app knows that it's located inside the PCL libraries if we don't specifiy it? It was a Runtime exception

Comment: But as far as i know it should work with string. Because you url is not proper it gave that exception.

Comment: @LovetoCode: Well, at least the code you provided me give this exception. After I changed the VM property to `Uri`, it goes a little bit further(but then I've a `ImageFailed` triggered from the Image element).

I added a screeshot of the folder in the initial question

Comment: Both were saying something that given ur is not proper

Comment: @LovetoCode First one was triggered while binding, just seems there was no implicit converter for this. Are you sure that this support String in UWP app?

Comment: Yes its supported. Problem is your resource folder is in different project and views are in different project. Any reason why did you put resource folder in model project instead in project where views are residing?

Comment: This worked for me Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibrary2/Resources/image.png" where ClassLibrary2 is different project. Did you add model project reference to your main project. Right now i can only think of that  is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image is in the same project as your MyModelContainer, this should work:

```
public class MyModel{
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public ImageSource Icon {get;set;}
}

public static class MyModelContainer{
    private static IEnumerable<MyModel> _myModelList;

    public static IEnumerable<MyModel> MyModelList{get{
        if(_myModelList==null){
            Initialize();
        }
        return _myModelList;
    }}

    private static Initialize(){
        _myModelList = new List<MyModel>() {
            new MyModel(){
                Name = "Model one"
                Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/image1.png"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If your image is in another assembly, use this url:

```
Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///NameOfProjectWithImage/Resources/image1.png"));
```

Comment: It is in the same project but not the same project as the XAML. I tried your example, but I still get no image bound and the event "Image.ImageFailed" is triggered :(

Comment: And if you try ms-appx:///NameOfProjectWithImage/Resources/image1.png?

Comment: Same thing(it's what I said I tried). What is the expected build action for the images?

Comment: In your question you use 2 slashes after "ms-appx" (ms-appx://) and I use 3 (ms-appx:///NameOfProject...) - can that be a reason?

Comment: I just noticed my error :( The correct way to do it is with your Second suggestion(`ms-appx:///NameOfProjectWithImage/Resources/image1.png`), but in fact in one of the image, I had a typo, so the breakpoint was hit and I tought that was the case for all the images, I'm so sorry. 
Could you update your answer to reflect the correct path and I will accept it?

Comment: added that to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.  I confirm the second option works perfectly the image source of toast notifications.